# Permission to record screen not showing outside the app in android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-permissions, android-windowmanager

I'm developing a simple screen recording app and it's working fine.
And I have created a floating widget that appears when a user opens up the app and when the app is running in the background.

When I press on the floating widget when I'm in the app the below dialog appears every time and if I press yes it starts recording and the same happens with the app which I download from the google play store.

[image]

But when I go outside my app if I press the floating widget again it doesn't pop up the above dialog while the app which I download from the play store does. And I noticed I more thing the floating widget of the app which I download from play store hides which showing that permission dialog.

[image]

Here is my service class which shows the floating widget

```
public class FloatingViewService extends Service {
    private WindowManager mWindowManager;
    private View mFloatingView;
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.mukesh.service";

    public FloatingViewService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //Inflate the floating view layout we created
        mFloatingView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_floating_widget, null);

        //Add the view to the window.
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
//              WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        //Specify the view position
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;        //Initially view will be added to top-left corner
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        //Add the view to the window
        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mWindowManager.addView(mFloatingView, params);


        //….
        //….

        //The root element of the collapsed view layout
        final View collapsedView = mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.collapse_view);
        //The root element of the expanded view layout
        final View expandedView = mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.expanded_container);


        //Set the close button
        ImageView closeButtonCollapsed = (ImageView) mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.close_btn);
        closeButtonCollapsed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //close the service and remove the from from the window
                stopSelf();
            }
        });


        //Set the view while floating view is expanded.
        //Set the start recording button.
        ImageView playButton = (ImageView) mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.startRecording);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(FloatingViewService.this, "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //serviceCallbacks.onClick(1);

                Intent temp = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
                temp.putExtra("type" , 1);
                sendBroadcast(temp);
            }
        });


        //stop recording.
        ImageView nextButton = (ImageView) mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.stopRecording);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(FloatingViewService.this, "recording stoped.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent temp = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
                temp.putExtra("type" , 2);
                sendBroadcast(temp);
            }
        });


        //Set the close button
        ImageView closeButton = (ImageView) mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.close_button);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                collapsedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                expandedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        //Drag and move floating view using user's touch action.
        mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.root_container).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;


            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                        //remember the initial position.
                        initialX = params.x;
                        initialY = params.y;


                        //get the touch location
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        int Xdiff = (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        int Ydiff = (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);


                        //The check for Xdiff <10 && YDiff< 10 because sometime elements moves a little while clicking.
                        //So that is click event.
                        if (Xdiff < 10 && Ydiff < 10) {
                            if (isViewCollapsed()) {
                                //When user clicks on the image view of the collapsed layout,
                                //visibility of the collapsed layout will be changed to "View.GONE"
                                //and expanded view will become visible.
                                collapsedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                expandedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        //Calculate the X and Y coordinates of the view.
                        params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);


                        //Update the layout with new X & Y coordinate
                        mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatingView, params);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


    }


    private boolean isViewCollapsed() {
        return mFloatingView == null || mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.collapse_view).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mFloatingView != null) mWindowManager.removeView(mFloatingView);
    }


}
```

Any suggestion, please

Answer (score 0):

Your service will work better after adding [foreground service](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/foreground-service) in FloatingViewService

But from [Android 10 there are some restrictions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts)

Resolve these and your service will work according to you.